# cannot find symbol import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService error in ionic3

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I Have no idea why I am getting this error whenever I try to create my app's build.I have tried many solutions but  I was unable to solve this.i don't know if any plugins is causing issues or if there's any issue with my Code or firebase or firebase connectivity.I have deleted node modules and run npm install and removed and re-added android platform but still i am getting this error.

```
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;
                              ^
  symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceIdService
  location: package com.google.firebase.iid
C:\Users\user\Downloads\mosque\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginInstanceIDService.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
public class FirebasePluginInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
                                                     ^
  symbol: class FirebaseInstanceIdService
C:\Users\user\Downloads\mosque\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:508: error: method getByteArray in class FirebaseRemoteConfig cannot be applied to given types;
                            : FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getByteArray(key, namespace);
                                                                ^
  required: String
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
C:\Users\user\Downloads\mosque\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:525: error: method getValue in class
FirebaseRemoteConfig cannot be applied to given types;
                            : FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getValue(key, namespace);
                                                                ^
  required: String
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
C:\Users\user\Downloads\mosque\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:579: error: no suitable method found
for setDefaults(Map<String,Object>,String)
                        FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().setDefaults(defaultsToMap(defaults), namespace);
                                                          ^
    method FirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(Map<String,Object>) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method FirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
C:\Users\user\Downloads\mosque\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginInstanceIDService.java:18: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\user\Downloads\mosque\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\io\card\cordova\sdk\CardIOCordovaPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
6 errors
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\user\Downloads\mosque\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginInstanceIDService.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;
                              ^
  symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceIdService
  location: package com.google.firebase.iid
C:\Users\user\Downloads\mosque\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginInstanceIDService.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
public class FirebasePluginInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
                                                     ^
  symbol: class FirebaseInstanceIdService
C:\Users\user\Downloads\mosque\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:508: error: method getByteArray in class FirebaseRemoteConfig cannot be applied to given types;
                            : FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getByteArray(key, namespace);
                                                                ^
  required: String
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
C:\Users\user\Downloads\mosque\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:525: error: method getValue in class
FirebaseRemoteConfig cannot be applied to given types;
                            : FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getValue(key, namespace);
                                                                ^
  required: String
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
C:\Users\user\Downloads\mosque\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:579: error: no suitable method found
for setDefaults(Map<String,Object>,String)
                        FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().setDefaults(defaultsToMap(defaults), namespace);
                                                          ^
    method FirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(Map<String,Object>) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method FirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
C:\Users\user\Downloads\mosque\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginInstanceIDService.java:18: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\user\Downloads\mosque\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\io\card\cordova\sdk\CardIOCordovaPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
6 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova build android exited with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Ok. This is a gradle error, and many people are facing the problem. I will keep helping you to find alternative ways.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, it's depreciated. The fix it quite simple, just move the code...

From `onTokenRefresh()` in your `FirebaseInstanceIdService` subclass

To `onNewToken()` in your `FirebaseMessagingService` subclass

Info on depreciation: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_april_02_2019

I would recommend making this small code change over using old versions of firebase. Probably a good idea to also migrate to AndroidX [https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate] while you're at it.

Comment: the method onNewToken() doesn't exist... are you sure?

Comment: @AriWaisberg just create the onNewToken() method in the FirebaseMessagingService and it will work.

Comment: @AriWaisberg the function definition looks like this  -> 

Override
    public void onNewToken(String refreshedToken), I think you're missing the parameter

Comment: @kaitlyn: i have alrady migrate AndroidX but same error again>

Answer (score 13):

This is due to the Firebase updates on April 05. Here https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_april_02_2019 96, I found the last working versions and adjusted my `project.properties` accordingly like so:

```
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8

cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0

cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.1

cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.4
```

Here all dependencies are locked to the specific version (Update - April 02, 2019) instead of **+**, which would get you the latest version thus breaking the build process.

Now I can build successfully! Hope it helps!

`project.properties` can be found on *platforms/android/project.properties*

Answer (score 11):

After serveral tests, my solution was change cordova-plugin-firebase by cordova-plugin-firebasex.
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase#migrating-from-cordova-plugin-firebase

```sh
rm -Rf platforms/android
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase
rm -Rf plugins/ node_modules/
npm install
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
cordova platform add android
```

I hope this helps.

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase#androidx

This plugin has been migrated to use AndroidX (Jetpack) which is the successor to the Android Support Library. This is implemented by adding a dependency on cordova-plugin-androidx which enables AndroidX in the Android platform of a Cordova project.

This is because the major release of the Firebase and Play Services libraries on 17 June 2019 were migrated to AndroidX.

Therefore if your project includes any plugins which are dependent on the legacy Android Support Library, you should add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter to your project. This plugin will dynamically migrate any plugin code from the Android Support Library to AndroidX equivalents.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. i think this is the right solution. no downgrades. no library code manipulations.

Comment: you save my life, really ! been struggling for 2 months with these bug  i buy you a beer  )))

Comment: This is a way better solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If this problem happens in **React Native** frameworks.There are two solutions:

## solution 1 *(recommended)*:

change firebase version in below files:
`android\app\build.gradle`

```
...
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
...
```

And in `android\gradle.properties` at the bottom of file add

```
firebaseCoreVersion=16.0.8
firebaseMessagingVersion=17.6.0
```

## solution 2:

Change `\node_modules\react-native-fcm\android\src\main\java\com\evollu\react\fcm\InstanceIdService.java` file as complete below.

```
package com.evollu.react.fcm;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
//import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService; //Commented FirebaseInstanceIdService
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;  //ADD FirebaseMessagingService

public class InstanceIdService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "InstanceIdService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. This call is initiated by the
     * InstanceID provider.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) { //Added onNewToken method
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // Broadcast refreshed token
        Intent i = new Intent("com.evollu.react.fcm.FCMRefreshToken");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("token", refreshedToken);
        i.putExtras(bundle);

        final Intent message = i;

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Construct and load our normal React JS code bundle
                ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager = ((ReactApplication) getApplication()).getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager();
                ReactContext context = mReactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();
                // If it's constructed, send a notification
                if (context != null) {
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(message);
                } else {
                    // Otherwise wait for construction, then send the notification
                    mReactInstanceManager.addReactInstanceEventListener(new ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener() {
                        public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext context) {
                            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(message);
                        }
                    });
                    if (!mReactInstanceManager.hasStartedCreatingInitialContext()) {
                        // Construct it in the background
                        mReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This issue occurs due to major firebase release to support AndroidX

**Solution:**

1. Remove android platform(I followed this step. but there should be workaround which I might not know) - `cordova platform rm android`
2. Remove old firebase plugin - 
   `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase`
3. Add new firebase plugin -
   `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex`
4. Again add platform -
   `cordova platform add android`

Now your build will succeed.

Comment: but i am  not using cordova-plugin-firebase plugin what i do in such case?

Comment: @Kapilsoni I think you used the one with OTP Auth.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This is a gradle error. This is due to the firebase updates in April, `FirebaseInstanceIdService` is deprecated, and many people are facing the problem.

[Check the reference documentation for FirebaseInstanceIdService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService)

> This class was deprecated.
>
> In favour of overriding onNewToken in FirebaseMessagingService. Once
>   that has been implemented, this service can be safely removed.

Comment: this is how we import firebase.iid

Comment: Ok. `FirebaseInstanceIdService` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

then use

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this... Use firebase messaging to get token.
**Reason**: FirebaseInstanceId is **deprecated**, so that won't work.

Below is an example of how to go about it.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<String> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    updateToken(task.getResult());
                }
            }
        });
```

**Hope this helps somebody**

Comment: .getToken is deprecated as well bro.

Answer (score 0):

In my case firebase ui auth latest library 8.0.0 was conflicting so I downgraded auth ui to 7.2.0

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'
```